# loading my library

Tags: android

There is my used project: http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/

when I try to run my project, I got a problem loading my library "pdfrender"
Here is the line causing the problem: `System.loadLibrary("pdfrender");`
In my project, I have a floader named jni and contain the library pdfrender.c

Here is my logcat:

```
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at de.hilses.droidreader.DroidReaderActivity.onCreate(DroidReaderActivity.java:108)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load pdfrender: findLibrary returned null
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at de.hilses.droidreader.PdfRender.<clinit>(PdfRender.java:111)
02-28 10:57:55.241: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1):

finally i found the solution we have to install ndk-android and cygwin. then we are able to build .so from .c file.

For more explanation you can see this, it helped me very much:
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Answer (score 0):

- > Couldn't load (library) pdfrender

If you build with eclipse make shure that the library pdfrender in the build-path **is marked as Exported** (checkbox before lib is set).

Then it should be included into the build apk-file

Comment: please i am new with Eclipse, how can i do this. i got pdfrender.c in jni folder!! i know how to import .jar library, not .c??

Comment: i have been reading the README of the open source project, and they say that, In order to build DroidReader, you need:

- the sources of DroidReader, but you managed that already...

- source code of the MuPDF software/library

- source code of libjpeg

- source code of freetype2

- the Android Native Development Kit (NDK)

- and of course the Android SDK.

Comment: sorry, i have no experience in combining java with native c/ndk